# Expand image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an image gallery, on image click the image is being expanded using this code:

```
var quadimages = document.querySelectorAll("#quad img");
for(i=0; i<quadimages.length; i++) {
  quadimages[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ this.classList.toggle("expanded")}); 
}
```

That's working fine- when one of the images on the gallery is being clicked, the image expands but how can I make the previous image that was expanded to return to it's default size?

```
<div id="quad">
  <img src="images/gallery/Homes/homes01.jpg">
  <img src="images/gallery/Homes/homes02.jpg">
  <img src="images/gallery/Homes/homes03.jpg">
  <img src="images/gallery/Homes/homes04.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tag this 'jquery' deliberately? There's no jquery in the code. But a jquery answer might be nicer than plain js.

Comment: @ChrisLear You're right, thanks for your comment, I edited my question to first include the javascript tag.

Comment: Simply iterate the images that are expanded in the event handler and toggle them before toggling the one you clicked on. The querySelector can be called with `#quad img .expanded`.

Answer (score 1):

> but how can I make the previous image that was expanded to return to
>   it's default size

```
 quadimages[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ 
         $("#quad img").removeClass('expanded');
         this.classList.toggle("expanded")});
```

Comment: Sure you can cache the `$("#quad img")` but that's another story

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery for the whole thing (which involves rewriting some of the working code):

```
var images = $("#quad img");
images.on('click', function() {
    images.removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
});
```

Using no jquery (based on existing code, and keeping track of the last element clicked, rather than always toggling all of them):

```
var quadimages = document.querySelectorAll("#quad img");
var lastClicked;
for(i=0; i<quadimages.length; i++) {
    quadimages[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.toggle("expanded");
        if (lastClicked) {
            lastClicked.classList.toggle('expanded');
        }
        lastClicked = this;
    });
}
```

Another non-jquery version, with slightly different behaviour when clicking the same image twice

```
var quadimages = document.querySelectorAll("#quad img");
for(i=0; i<quadimages.length; i++) {
    quadimages[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var ex = document.querySelectorAll("#quad img.expanded");
        if (ex.length) {
            if (ex[0]!=this) {
                ex[0].classList.remove('expanded');
            }
        }
        this.classList.toggle("expanded");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var quadimages = document.querySelectorAll("#quad img");
for(i=0; i<quadimages.length; i++) {
  quadimages[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ 
  $('.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
  this.classList.toggle("expanded")}); 
}
```

Try this, It'll work in you case I hope. :)